# VueJS : Trigger function to fill up a select at the loading of the form

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have this code

```
<template>
    <h5>Add to a mailchimp list</h5>
    <div class="form-group">
       <label>Connexion Mailchimp</label>
       <select class="form-control" v-model="trigger.connexion_id" @change="updateTrigger(trigger)">
          <option value="">Choose</option>
          <option v-if="connexion.service == 'mailchimp'" v-for="connexion in connexions" v-bind:value="connexion.id">{{ connexion.name }}</option>
       </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label>List</label>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-10">
                <select class="form-control" @mounted="getMailchimpLists(trigger.connexion_id)" @change="updateTrigger(trigger)" v-model="trigger.data.listid" >
                <option value="">Choose a list</option>
                <option v-if="mailchimp_lists" v-for="list in mailchimp_lists" v-bind:value="list.id" :selected="list.id == trigger.data.listid">{{ list.name }}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
           <button class="btn btn-outline-dark" @click="getMailchimpLists(trigger.connexion_id)"><i class="fas fa-sync"></i></button>
        </div>
     </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

And the javascript

```
data() {
    return {
        mailchimp_lists : [],
        errors : {}
    };
},
methods:{
            getMailchimpLists(connexionId){

               axios
               .get('/api/mailchimp/lists?connexion_id='+connexionId)
               .then(result => {
                   this.mailchimp_lists = result.data;
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    this.errors = error;
                });
            }
```

When i click on the following button i get my lists form Mailchimp and it works

What i try to do, it's execute the function at the loading of the select. I tryied with @load, @mount... Nothing works.

How can i do this ?

Edit :

What i'm globally coding is a kind of page builder with blocks. 
Each blocks as fields and is optional. And this select is a part of a block.
This part of code it's just a little part of my code.

For this reason i think i can't use the global mounted() event because at the loading of the page the blocks of my select doesn't exist yet and i don't have the parameters "connexion"

But i thought i can call a custom function like using @mounted directly on the select. However, this doesn't work :(

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Your select v-model should be v-model="mailchimp_lists". Place your ajax request in the created() life cycle method.

Comment: What about calling the function on page load? Use `"mounted"`

Comment: What do you mean when you say `I precise that this select is conditional one. It can be not loaded at the mounted() every time.`? Isn't that what you're trying to achieve with `@mounted="getMailchimpLists(trigger.connexion_id)"`?

Comment: @Ayrton i edited the bottom of my post to explain you more.

Comment: @TomShaw i can't change the name of my model beause i use this to save in database.

Comment: @Effection i can't. I edited the bottom of my post to explain you

Comment: mailchimp_lists : null, and use mounted

Answer (score 0):

There is no mounted event, it is a lifecycle method. I don't know where the trigger object is in your code, maybe it is computed data? but anyway make sure you have access to it in this template. Also you shall init the conexion param in your local data in order to use it in template. init it to an empty object. The array mailchimp_lists is always true, check mailchimp_lists.length. Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

You have two misconceptions about `mounted`:

- It's not an event. It's a *[lifecycle hook](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks)*, it is executed as part of the lifecycle of your component.
- It isn't fired once at page load. It's fired for *any Vue component* whenever it is mounted (that is, rendered and ready to function). So it will run every time your component is mounted, and if you destroy your component by using `v-if` then it will run again when it's recreated.

As an example of my second point, you can check out this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yaw1892u/).

To add the `mounted` hook to your component simply add it to your component's declaring object like this:

```
data() {
    return {
        mailchimp_lists : [],
        errors : {}
    };
},
methods: {
    getMailchimpLists(connexionId){
        axios.get('/api/mailchimp/lists?connexion_id='+connexionId)
        .then(result => {
            this.mailchimp_lists = result.data;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.errors = error;
        });
    }
},
mounted: function() {
    // Your code goes here
}
```